# Inkscape: How to have many shapes with exactly the same gradient

Tags: gradient, inkscape

I created a *flowchart* in **InkScape** in which each shape is filled with a linear gradient.

Some shapes share the same gradient tones but when I created them via copy&past did not know that gradients could be transformed during edit, I thought that copy&pasting a shape simply copy the entire object and each colors.

Anyway, it resulted in *shapes that changes background gradient during re-positioning*. After several searches I discovered that this is caused by a wrong position of "**Gradient Editor Tool**" of each one. In other words I moved objects but start/end of each gradient remained in place.

Please, how to quickly reposition gradient direction/start/end of each shape, maybe centering it on each one? I would avoid to manually reposition each one...

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure if this question is within scope of Stackoverflow, which, after all, is about programming.

Answer (score 1):

Inkscape provides a toggle button to move the gradients along with the objects.

[image]

Activating this button during any coying or moving carries the gradient with it to the new location. (Actually it copies the gradient.)

Comment: Thanks, I effectively found this option after searches about which I spoke in question :-) But actually my question is a ittle different. Now that I have the problem, in which each shape ha a wrong position of its gradient vector, is there a way to tell InkScape: "Not regarding its actual position, center each gradient vector to its shape" in other words... restore situation that I would have if I used button toggle that you suggested?

Comment: Edit:Undo ? Or restart from scratch. Of course you could try to manipulate the gradients programmatically, but I doubt this would be worth the effort.

Comment: Where is this button?